# Inserting bash script in python code

Tags: python, bash, grep, pipe

I am trying to execute a bash script from python code. The bash script has some grep commands in a pipe inside a for loop. When I run the bash script itself it gives no errors but when I use it within the python code it says: grep:write error.

The command that I call in python is:

```
subprocess.call("./change_names.sh",shell=True)
```

The bash script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for file in *.bam;do new_file=`samtools view -h $file | grep -P '\tSM:' | head -n 1 | sed 's/.\+SM:\(.\+\)/\1/' | sed 's/\t.\+//'`;rename s/$file/$new_file.bam/ $file;done
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Might help if you also post your bash script

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: Try using `subprocess.Popen()` instead.

Comment: I usually use `subprocess.check_output("bash script.sh", shell=True)` without any problem

Comment: It will probably be easier and cleaner if you avoid bash and use pysam to get the operation.

Comment: @politinsa thank you for your suggestion but it gives the same error

Comment: @Poshi thank you for introducing me to Pysam

Comment: @RoadRunner That is not helpful. If you replace `check_output` with `Popen()` you will need to reimplement the rest of `check_output()`. Most people who try manage to botch it because `Popen()` is a hard beast to tame.

Comment: ... or `subprocess.call()`, sorry I got these two mixed up between the comments and the question.

Comment: @tripleee Fair enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `shell=True` when you are running a simple command which doesn't require the shell for anything in the command line.

```
subprocess_call(["./change_names.sh"])
```

There are multiple problems in the shell script.  Here is a commented refactoring.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for file in *.bam; do
    # Use modern command substitution syntax; fix quoting
    new_file=$(samtools view -h "$file" |
        grep -P '\tSM:' |
        # refactor to a single sed script
        sed -n 's/.\+SM:\([^\t]\+\).*/\1/p;q')
    # Fix quoting some more; don't use rename
    mv "$file" "$new_file.bam"
done
```

`grep -P` doesn't seem to be necessary or useful here, but without an example of what the input looks like, I'm hesitant to refactor that into the `sed` script too.  I hope I have guessed correctly what your `sed` version does with the `\+` and `\t` escapes which aren't entirely portable.

This will still produce a warning that you are not reading all of the output from `grep` in some circumstances. A better solution is probably to refactor even more of this into your Python script.

```
import glob

for file in glob.glob('*.bam'):
    new_name = subprocess.check_output(['samtools', 'view', '-h', file])
    for line in new_name.split('\n'):
        if '\tSM:' in line:
            dest = line.split('\t')[0].split('SM:')[-1] + '.bam'
            os.rename(file, dest)
            break
```

Comment: See also [actual meaning of `shell=True` in `subprocess`](/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

Comment: The modified shell script gives the expected results although the error is persisting: grep:write error:Broken pipe.

Comment: That’s a harmless warning which indicates that you are not reading all the output from `grep`. It can be avoided if you think it’s important; but again, avoiding `grep` altogether is what I recommend here.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try with below modification which will fix your issue.

```
for file in *.bam;do new_file=`unbuffer samtools view -h $file | grep -P '\tSM:' | head -n 1 | sed 's/.\+SM:\(.\+\)/\1/' | sed 's/\t.\+//'`;rename s/$file/$new_file.bam/ $file;done
```

Or else try to redirect your standard error to dev/null like below

```
for file in *.bam;do new_file=`samtools view -h $file >2>/dev/null | grep -P '\tSM:' | head -n 1 | sed 's/.\+SM:\(.\+\)/\1/' | sed 's/\t.\+//'`;rename s/$file/$new_file.bam/ $file;done
```

Your actual issue is with this command `samtools view -h $file` While you are running the script from `python` you should provide a full path like below:-

```
/fullpath/samtools view -h $file
```

Comment: Using the unbuffer gives error. Could you explain why the command samtools view -h $file is the actual issue?

Comment: if a standard error redirect to grep command it gives `grep:write error`. Did you tried with `/fullpath/samtools view -h $file `?

Comment: I tried with /fullpath/samtools view -h $file but it gives the same error: grep:write error:Broken pipe. However, the results are correct.

Comment: This preserves all the quoting errors in the original code. Don’t use this.